# ListView Behavior for AutoScrolling that stops at user interaction

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

i try to use the new Behavior-Feature in UAP. I use this Behavior:

```
public sealed class AutoScrollToLastItemBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    private bool _collectionChangedSubscribed;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
        AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged += DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollToBottom();
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollToBottom();
    }

    private void DataContextChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var collection = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection == null || _collectionChangedSubscribed) return;

        collection.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        _collectionChangedSubscribed = true;
    }

    private void ScrollToBottom()
    {
        var selectedIndex = AssociatedObject.Items?.Count - 1;

        if (!selectedIndex.HasValue || selectedIndex < 0)
            return;

        AssociatedObject.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex.Value;
        AssociatedObject.UpdateLayout();
        AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(AssociatedObject.SelectedItem);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= SelectionChanged;
        AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged -= DataContextChanged;

        var collection = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as  INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection == null || !_collectionChangedSubscribed) return;
        collection.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;
        _collectionChangedSubscribed = false;
    }
}
```

This code works well. But i would like that the AutoScrolling stoped when user interact with the ListView. I found some sampels but most of them based on WPF and some of the functions or properties are not present in UWP.

So actual i dont finde a way to implementate a AutoScroll that stop working if the User scrolls by it self. Have someone maybe an idear for this?

Greetings

Comment: What do you mean when you say "AutoScrolling" ?

Comment: Think on a ChatTool. A new Message comes in and and the Chat Scrolls to the End (That is what i mean with AutoScroll, it AutoScrolled to the last Item inserted). But now the user would like to read a message in the Bottom of the Chat and the the AutoScroll would break his plan. And thats actual my problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by "user interacting with a `ListView`". If you mean someone scrolling manually - you can check the `ViewChanged` event or `VerticalOffset` of the `ScrollViewer` to see if it's scrolled to the bottom before collection change. Other interactions are likely things that are custom to your app, so you would have to detect them yourself. You need to access the `ScrollViewer` from the `ListView` template first before you look at these details.